# Center Toolbar buttons for Froala Editor

Tags: position, froala

The buttons on the Froala editor toolbar are all left aligned. Is it possible to center them?
See in the attached image all the buttons are left aligned, I would like to be able to center them.

[image: Froala toolbar]